# IDT Audio Codec and Driver

Tags: audio, windows-10, codec

Can using an old IDT audio codec driver (Version:6.10.6233.266)  and a new IDT audio codec chip (93HD68D) cause any issue?

I am facing issues with hearing audio in my laptop. It stops intermittently and doesn't resolve with a warm reboot. Only a hard reboot solves the issue.